# react-native-webview:clean :Unable to delete directory

Tags: android, react-native

react-native

```
cd android
.\gradlew clean
```

error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-webview:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory 'C:****\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\build'
    Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
    - C:****\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\build\intermediates\library_java_res\debug\res.jar
```